# OpenCL ATI Stream SDK on Nvidia GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, ati

Can I code my OpenCL application on an Nvidia GPU by installing ATI Stream SDK (as it will allow me to accelerate my CPU too which Nvidia programming SDK won't) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have more than one platform (meaning: OpenCL implementation) installed on a machine. So even if you have a NVIDIA GPU, you can use the AMD OpenCL implementation for CPUs (or the Intel OpenCL SDK if you have an Intel CPU). However you can't use the AMD OpenCL implementation to run code on the NVIDIA GPU.

With this small utility lib you can easily select which implementation/platform to use: http://www.thebigblob.com/opencl-utilities/

Comment: [Off Topic]@Erik Smistad: your website is very useful! It help me a lot of time.[/Off Topic]
Your OpenCL C++ lib is great. I create my own OpenCL C++ lib too. I find the official OpenCL C++ wrapper poor. I think you already know the AMD APP SDK and the C++ SDKUtils ( ..\Documents\AMD APP\samples\opencl\SDKUtil ), but it help me to create my lib.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the AMD SDK to build the host program and then target as many different devices as you want - CPU, NVIDIA GPU, whatever. But make sure you have separate versions of your OpenCL code that are optimized for each device.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. In OpenCL terms, you won't be able to create a context that combines devices from several platforms (e.g. Nvidia GPU + Intel CPU, as in the OP): https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=1941.

Comment: ...and the AMD platform doesn't list Nvidia GPUs, I just checked that out with the most recent AMD APP SDK.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou, I didn't say anything about combining devices in a context OR using the AMD platform to access NVIDIA GPUs. This is about COMPILING the program with AMD SDK.